# XSL Transformation Assistance Needed

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

I am trying to transform an xml file to another xml file using XSL 1.0.

The source file contains unwanted emphasis elements that I need to drop in the output. In the following example, you will see `<emphasis>` are used to describe text that occurs within a `<p>`. In the first instance, `<emphasis type="i">` contains another `<emphasis type="i">`. In the second instance the `<emphasis type="i">` contains an `<emphasis>` that contains another `<emphasis type="i">`.

```
<!-- 1st instance --><para>Text text text text text <emphasis type="i">italicized text 
<emphasis type="i">more italicized text</emphasis>, text text text text text text</emphasis>. 
Text text text text text<!-- 2nd instance --><emphasis type="i"><emphasis>
<emphasis type="i">italicized text</emphasis>, text text text text text </emphasis> text text
text text text text</emphasis> text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text .</p>
```

In the first instance, I need to keep the wrapper, strip the second `<emphasis type="i">` and keep the text so that it appears as so:

`<p>`Text text text text text `<emphasis type="i">`italicized text more italicized text, text text text text text text`</emphasis>`

In the second instance, I need to keep the wrapper `<emphasis type="i">` but strip the `<emphasis>` and the next `<emphasis type="i">` so that it appears as so:

```
<emphasis type="i">italicized text, text text text text text text text text text text
text</emphasis> text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text .</p>
```

I have tried matching emphasis and choosing when @type ='i' and when Child::emphasis [type='i']

I have tried matching emphasis/emphasis and choosing when @type='i'

I have tried matching p and using for-each select emphasis/emphasis[type='i'] and outputting value of select .

I have tried matching p and for-each select emphasis[type='i']/emphasis/emphasis[type='i']

I don't know how to output the text without the unwanted `<emphasis>`. I can submit the code i used if that would be helpful, but I really doubt it will do anyone any good :)

I would sincerely appreciate any assistance anyone can offer.

In addition to the italic attribute, this same scenario could occur for bold, underline caps and quotes. In all instances I need to find the attribute type of the wrapper `<emphasis>` and if the nested `<emphasis>` contain the same attribute, I need to remove them. The nested, unwanted `<emphasis>` are causing havoc in my publishing system.

Here is an example with actual sentence structure. I hope this helps:

```
`<!-- 1st instance -->``<p>`This is the text that is in the first paragraph that is not 
affected by the emphasis . . .; `<emphasis type="i">`however, this information is 
italicized`<emphasis type="i">`, and this information is also italicized text`</emphasis>`, 
and this is a continuation of the italicized information marked by the first 
emphasis`</emphasis>`.  The paragraph continues and this text is not affected by the 
emphasis . . . `<!-- 2nd instance -->``<emphasis type="i">`Although this is marked as italics,
in the original example, there wasn’t any text appearing here, but`<emphasis>`
`<emphasis type="i">`the text that follows is italicized and is contained within three sets of
emphasis`</emphasis>`, while this text is contained in two,`</emphasis>` this is contained in 
one,`</emphasis>` and finally, this is the remainder of the paragraph.`</p>`
```

Comment: Could you post a clearer example, please? Such as dividing your text parts into **recognizable** sentences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly guessing, but try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<!--  first instance -->
<xsl:template match="emphasis[@type=parent::emphasis/@type]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</xsl:template>


<!--  second instance -->
<xsl:template match="emphasis[parent::emphasis[not(@type)] and @type=ancestor::emphasis[2]/@type]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="emphasis[not(@type)]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Applied to your new example, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- 1st instance -->
<p>This is the text that is in the first paragraph that is not 
affected by the emphasis . . .; <emphasis type="i">however, this information is 
italicized, and this information is also italicized text, 
and this is a continuation of the italicized information marked by the first 
emphasis</emphasis>.  The paragraph continues and this text is not affected by the 
emphasis . . . <!-- 2nd instance --><emphasis type="i">Although this is marked as italics,
in the original example, there wasn’t any text appearing here, butthe text that follows is italicized and is contained within three sets of
emphasis, while this text is contained in two, this is contained in 
one,</emphasis> and finally, this is the remainder of the paragraph.</p>
```

Comment: Sorry. I was commenting and got interrupted. My comment must have timed out. I have tried your code in several different processors and the unnecessary emphasis are not being removed for me.

Comment: @123CSRPIN Are you getting result that is different from what I show, or is this not the correct result?

Comment: When I run the transformation against the paragraph I provided as an example, I get the same result as you. When I run it against my actual document, none of the emphasis are removed. Additionally, as I mentioned to @Joel, I just realized that the emphasis that does not contain an attribute defaults to bold (type="b"), so I don't want to remove it.

Comment: "*When I run it against my actual document, none of the emphasis are removed.*" I am afraid I can't help you with that, because I don't see your actual document. The responsibility to provide a **representative** example is yours. -- "*I just realized that the emphasis that does not contain an attribute defaults to bold (type="b"), so I don't want to remove it.*" I suggest you edit your question and formulate clearly the rules for removing the emphasis. Or - preferably, IMHO - just adapt the solutions that have been suggested here to your needs by yourself.

Comment: I have edited your code of the second instance: 
<xsl:template match="emphasis[parent::emphasis[not(@type)] and @type=ancestor::emphasis[2]/@type]">
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</xsl:template>                                                                                                                          I now receive the desired results if I remove the namespace that appears in my xml file before I run the translation. I don't understand why this is happening since I included the namespace in my xsl file. But, when removed, it works. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you could try the following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="emphasis[@type=ancestor::emphasis/@type]">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

it will remove emphasis tags with an attribute value equal to its ancestor's emphasis attribute value.

Comment: Thanks Joel, but this isn't working form me. I am new to XSL and I am not sure of the cause, but I am receiving many errors of the following effect:  Matches both "node()" on line 7 of file:/C:/XXX/XXX/Desktop/neww2irm.xsl
and "node()" on line 0 of null

Comment: Post your xsl at xsltransform.net and save it. Get the link and post it here.

Comment: OK. I got this to work. I was applying your code to my actual document and did not include the documents namespace. Anyway, the transformation removes the excess emphasis. Now, my only issue is that I did not realize that the emphasis that does not contain an attribute is actually type="b", so I don't want to remove it. Is this an easy modification? As I mentioned, I am new to XSL, so thank you for being patient.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Because the emphasis that do not contain an attribute is defined as `emphasis[not(@*)]`, I have removed `or not(@*)` from the predicate. Try it again.

Comment: Thank you. I have also edited your code and it works if I remove the namespace from my xml file. Again, I don't understand why this happens. The xml file will not translate properly when the namespace that appears in my xml file is present, even though I have included it in my xsl. I appreciate that help you have provided.

Comment: I think what you are saying is a default namespace, as `xmlns="www.example.com"`. If that is the case, you should register that in your stylesheet as, e.g., `xmlns:ex="www.example.com"` and refer that in your xpaths, say, `<xsl:template match="ex:emphasis[@type=ancestor::ex:emphasis/@type]"`

Comment: That is perfect! Thank you so much!!! I have been ripping my hair out over this for days. I sincerely appreciate your help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

This solution was provided by a co-worker and it seems to solve my issue:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="*[name(..)=name()]">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks so much for your willingness to help!

Comment: Note that this does not answer your question as asked. For example, this will remove a `<para>` tag nested in another `<para>`. What's worse, it will also remove a `<emphasis type="i">` tag, if it's nested inside a `<emphasis type="b">` block.